# Linux remove space/column if matching string pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut

I would like awk or sed or any other display filter mechanisms in native shell to be able to remove space from string lines that a match & do not remove any space between the 2 strings (columns) when not matched. And then display the output.

My file:

```
# cat test2
col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
ln1 abc def ghi jkl mno
ln2 abc defghi jkl mno pqr
```

My output I would like to be:

```
# <something to view/grep/filter with> test2
col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
ln1 abc defghi jkl mno
ln2 abc defghi jkl mno pqr
```

I have tried multiple combinations of grep & awk & cut. But not able to do it. I am not good with sed, but I can try. I even tried to use an interim file i.e. echo output to some file & then grep. But I failed to do that too.

*Edited with more of my requirement:*

My biggest problem is that I can't predict where the space will be & what the contents of the row entries would be. So I would like sed to get the output not based on a specific string but instead based on column numbers.

My file:

```
# cat test2
col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
ln1 abc def ghi jkl mno
ln2 abc defghi jkl mno pqr
ln3 aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
ln4 aaa bbbccc ddd eee
```

Output File:

```
# <something to view/grep/filter with> test2
col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
ln1 abc def ghi jkl mno
ln2 abc defghi jkl mno pqr
ln3 aaa bbbccc ddd eee
ln4 aaa bbbccc ddd eee
```

Comment: Your edited question brings no clarity as to what the criteria are.  Why is a space removed on line 3?  What's the rule or pattern you need help with?  If it's always the third line then `sed '3s/ / /2'` (if your `sed` supports the /2 flag to replace the second occurrence).  If the output needs to be five columns, why are not the first and second lines changed in your example?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/def ghi/defghi/' file
```

If that's not what you wanted then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide input/output that better demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. But I would like to request for a small modification. Is it possible with a column no. instead of the actual text in the column. Since the row lines will keep changing in my case. For example if my original file is like the below, then the above solution wont work. `col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
ln1 abc def ghi jkl mno
ln2 abc defghi jkl mno pqr
ln3 aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
ln4 aaa bbbccc ddd eee fff`

Comment: You can't put formatted text in a comment so don't try. If your question doesn't adequately capture your requirements, then just edit your question so it does. Of course since you left it 2 days before following up, chances are no-ones going to be looking at it any more so YMMV on getting an answer now.